# How to cache OAuth2RestTemplate with a cusom grant_type in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-oauth2, requestscope

I have seen similar threads but mine is different in that I am using a custom `grant type`. To give you a background, when we call a micro-service from another one, we use a `delegation` token that has the details of the user who initiated the call. So the user *U1* calls *S1* and *S1* calls *S2* so that *S2* uses the *U1* details for auditing and permission purposes.

Now to achieve this we have the following configuration for `OAuth2RestTemplate`:

```
    @Bean(name = "delegationResource")
    @Autowired
    public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails delegationResource(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationSettings settings) {
        OAuth2AuthenticationSettings authSettings = authenticationSettings != null ? authenticationSettings : new OAuth2AuthenticationSettings();
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
        url.append(settings.getAuthorisationUrl() != null ? settings.getAuthorisationUrl() : authSettings.getUrl());
        url.append(settings.getAccessTokenPath());

        DelegationResourceDetails details = new DelegationResourceDetails(authenticationFacade);
        details.setClientId(settings.getClientId());
        details.setClientSecret(settings.getClientSecret());
        details.setAccessTokenUri(url.toString());
        details.setGrantType("custom");
        if(settings.getScopes() != null) {
            details.setScope(Arrays.asList(settings.getScopes()));
        }
        return details;
    }

    @Bean(name = "requestScopeClientContext")
    @Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS) //Without request-scope, RestTemplate is not thread-safe
    public OAuth2ClientContext requestScopeClientContext() {
        //This is used for delegation requests and needs to be scoped as request otherwise the first token will be used for all other subsequent calls regardless of what user is initiating it
        return new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext();
    }

    @Autowired
    CorrelationIDInterceptor correlationIDInterceptor;

    @Bean(name = "delegationOauth2RestTemplate")
    //if access to a third party resource is required, a new bean should be created with a @Qualifier
    @Autowired
    public OAuth2RestTemplate clientCredentialDelegationOauth2RestTemplate(@Qualifier("delegationResource") OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails delegationResource, @Qualifier("requestScopeClientContext")  OAuth2ClientContext sessionScopeClientContext) {
        /*
        This is used to send requests from a micro-service to another on behalf of the user who initiated the original request
        so this has to have a thread-safe client-context
         */
        ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> clientHttpRequestInterceptors = new ArrayList<>();
        clientHttpRequestInterceptors.add(correlationIDInterceptor);
        DelegationOAuth2RestTemplate delegationOAuth2RestTemplate = new DelegationOAuth2RestTemplate(delegationResource, sessionScopeClientContext);
        delegationOAuth2RestTemplate.setInterceptors(clientHttpRequestInterceptors);
        return delegationOAuth2RestTemplate;
    }
```

As you can see `OAuth2ClientContext` has to be in `request` scope otherwise the previous user details will be used and token generation won't happen for second user and so on.

But this has some performance impacts. The effect becomes more visible when we have many concurrent users. So as a solution, I'm thinking to cache `OAuth2ClientContext` per user with a cache expiry set to a value less than the token expiry. Although cache expiry isn't really an issue because each token will be validated before getting this point.

Now the question is how do I achieve this and what is the best way? From my understanding I need to change the scope from `request` to `singleton` like the default Spring bean's scope and then somehow make it to create a new instance when there is no entry in the cache? Not sure how to do this though?

Answer (score 0):

OK I am answering my question as I went through some pages and tested different scenarious with this solution all of which worked well.

So I've modified the method that creates a new `OAuth2ClientContext` to get it from a cached method:

```
    @Bean(name = "requestScopeClientContext")
    @Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS) //Without request-scope, RestTemplate is not thread-safe
    public OAuth2ClientContext requestScopeClientContext() {
        if(!authenticationSettings.getDisableCachedToken()) {
            String username = authenticationFacade.getPrincipal().getUsername();
            DefaultOAuth2ClientContext occ = cachedService.getOAuth2ClientContextByUser(username);
            logger.debug("DefaultOAuth2ClientContext is fetched with id {} for user {}", occ.hashCode(), username);
            return occ;
        } else {
            logger.debug("DefaultOAuth2ClientContext has not been cached!");
            return new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext();
        }
    }
```

And this is the cached method:

```
@Service
public class CachedService {

    /**
     * The <code>principal</code> argument is used as an entry for the underlying cache so that
     * Spring doesn't call to issue new token if there is already available for that user.
     * The option <code>sync</code> is set to true for concurrent requests, if not true all the calls to this method will initiate cache calculation
     * before the cache being updated even if they are all the same user, setting true ensures the first call does the computation and the
     * rest will benefit from the cache.
     * @param principal
     * @return
     */
    @Cacheable(value = "delegation", sync = true, key = "#principal", cacheManager = "caffeine")
    public DefaultOAuth2ClientContext getOAuth2ClientContextByUser(String principal) {
        System.out.println("CALLED");
        //This is used for delegation requests and needs to be scoped as request otherwise the first token will be used for all other subsequent calls regardless of what user is initiating it
        return new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext();
    }
}
```

As you can see there is an argument `principal` that hasn't been used in the method itself but it's important for the cache to have a key to return the right instance of the `OAuth2ClientContext`.

I have tested this with short-time and long-time expiry for the cache, the former with a time shorter than token expiry time and the latter with a time longer than token's expiry date:

In both cases `OAuth2ClientContext` is smartly requesting for new token if the token is expired or not available at all.

So no issue and works like a charm.